# How to prevent a page from resubmitting? in grails 2.2.0

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

When once form is submitted successfully....

but When I click on **"BACK"** button and trying submit same form
its gives me an error [image]

Source:

```
<g:form action="addData" name="addValues" controller="emp" method="Post">
</g:form>
```

Controller Source:-

```
def editProfile (Long id,Long version){
        withForm {
        // code
            }.invalidToken {
            response.status = 405

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to infer the cause of the error with what you have posted. However, you asked about how to prevent a page from resubmitting in Grails. Take a look at [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#formtokens). Grails has a build in support for that.
Basically you define a form with a token and using `withForm` you will check if the token still is valid or not.

```
<g:form useToken="true" ...>
```

/

```
withForm {
   // good request
}.invalidToken {
   // bad request
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alidad for your response.. but after doing this... still its shows me a same error...

Comment: Hey @alidad .. sorry.. this code is working fine.. i just restarted my project and code working fine .. Thanks for your helping